# Android TextView `ifAtLineStart` method?

Tags: android, newline, android-edittext

this might be a simple question, but I was wondering if there was a way to tell if the cursor in an `EditText` is at the start of a line or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `myedittext.getSelectionStart()` to get the current position of cursor.

For furthur info you can see: [developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html)